# Fake services mock for local development

Tags: soap, service, soa, distributed

This has happend to me more than once, thought someone can give some insight.

I have worked on multiple projects where my project depends on external service. When I have to run the application locally, i would need that service to be up. But sometimes I would be coding to the next version of their service which may not be ready.

So the question is, is there already a way that can have a mock service up and running that i could configure with some request and responses?

For example, lets say that I have a local application that needs to make a rest call to some other service outside to obtain some data. E.g, say, for given a user, i need to find all pending shipments which would come from other service. But I dont have access to that service.

In order to run my application, i need a working external service but I dont have access to it in my environment. Is there a better way rather than having to create a fake service?

Answer (score 3):

You should separate the communications concerns from your business logic (something I call "Edge Component" see [here](http://arnon.me/soa-patterns/edge-component/) and [here](http://rgoarchitects.bit.ly/6wTGjM)).

For one it will let you test the business logic by itself. It will also give you the opportunity to rethink the temporal coupling you currently have. e.g. you may want the layer that handle communications to pre-fetch, cache etc. data from other services so that you will also have more resilient services at run time